# How can I test if an integerForKey is equal to nil? Using NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

So far, I have a function that tries to see if someone already has a code, and if they do not already have one, then it would generate one for them. 
 func checkID() -> Int{

```
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Code") != nil) {

    }
    else{
        var code = Int(arc4random_uniform(1000000000))
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(code, forKey: "Code")
    }
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Code")
}
```

I get an error message when I try to to say NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Code") != nil

The error message I get is "Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'"

What can I do to try to get around this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: integerForKey returns 0 if the key does not exist: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/integerForKey:

Answer (score 16):

The `integerForKey` always returns a value. If nothing's there, just 0.

So you should check like that:

```
if let currentValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Code"){
    //Exists
}else{
    //Doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "you can't." There's no way to tell if a zero result for integerForKey represents a stored zero value, or no value.

Christian's answer of using objectForKey (which returns an optional) and optional binding is the correct answer.

### Edit:

It would be quite easy to add an extension to UserDefaults with a function that returned an Optional Int:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func int(forKey key: String) -> Int? {
        return object(forKey: key) as? Int
    }
}
```

(I suspect that if Apple were designing the Foundations framework today, using Swift, `integer(forKey:)` would return an `Optional(Int)`.)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to remove the '!= nil'. For instance,

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Code")) {

}
else{
    var code = Int(arc4random_uniform(1000000000))
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(code, forKey: "Code")
}
return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Code")
```

Simply retrieving the value of the key should return false if the integer is not found.

Comment: I get another error message saying "Type 'int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'."